# How to set rate limit in laravel with nextjs on frontend?

Tags: laravel, next.js, rate-limiting

I'm using Next.js for the website's front-end and Laravel for the back-end. Next.js doesn't automatically send the user's IP address when it talks to the back-end server. Instead, it sends the IP address of the front-end server itself. This becomes a problem when multiple users are making requests, as they all appear to have the same IP address from the perspective of the back-end server. When too many requests come in from this same IP address (the front-end server), it hits a limit and can't handle any more, causing the web page to fail to load and redirecting users to a 404 error page.

I attempted to send the IP address from Next.js, but it doesn't have that feature. So, I need to request an external API to get the IP address. However, I'd rather not fetch the external API and send the IP address to my backend API.

Or should I remove the rate limit from backend?

I need suggestions.

Comment: can you set/change headers from next.js when you call APIs? If you can then get user's IP in the front end and set it in your API request's header.

Comment: You are looking for:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For